# Get user profile link from Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app-scoped user id (ASUID) for a Facebook user and I wish to obtain a link to that user's profile page.

A [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/) on Facebook's Developer blog dated May 1, 2018 states that this link is accessible as of Graph API v3.0 through the `link` field on a user object. Access to this field requires the `user_link` permission be approved for the app and granted by the app user.

I have attempted to access this field with a user access token associated with my test app and I have verified the access token has the `user_link` permission granted via the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/). However, the link is not included in the response.

> Request:
>
> `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/[ASUID]?fields=link&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN_W_USER_LINK_PERMISSION]`
>
> Response:
>
> `{ "id": "[ASUID]" }`

Is there any indication as to why this is not working?

Comment: This works fine for me with a “real” app, but not if I switch to an actual _test_ app “clone”, in Graph API Explorer. My guess would be that Facebook has restricted this for test apps, to exclude that feature gets abused or something.

Answer (score 1):

As documented, the [`user_link`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/?locale=en_US#reference-user_link) permission requires an [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) pass before it's available to live apps.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing this answer there is no way to get user profile page using Facebook API.